# Setting Layer Visibility in OL3

Tags: openlayers

I am trying to toggle visibility of a GeoServer WMS layer.

The code below **doesn't** render the layer, regardless of if `setVisibility` is `true` or `false`

```
var countryParks = new ol.layer.Tile({
                 title: 'Country Parks',
                 source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
                 url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/opengeo/wms',
                 params: {"LAYERS": 'opengeo:country_parks'},
                 serverType: 'geoserver'    }),
});
countryParks.setVisibility(true);
map.addLayer(countryParks);
```

And this code **does** render the layer, `true` or `false` regardless

```
var countryParks = new ol.layer.Tile({
                 title: 'Country Parks',
                 visiblity: false,
                 source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
                 url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/opengeo/wms',
                 params: {"LAYERS": 'opengeo:country_parks'},
                 serverType: 'geoserver'    }),
});
map.addLayer(countryParks);
```

How does one toggle layer visibility, if not as in these attempts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In ol-3 the property is called **visible** and **setVisible()** not "visiblity" - see [API](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.6.0/apidoc/ol.layer.Tile.html)